# How to use find method to extract values using start and end

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe(sample_emails) that provides a list of emails and I would like to extract only the workplace from the email. For example from the email such as person1@uber.com, it should return only the string "uber". I tried writing the code for this but I keep getting a variety of errors.

```
extract_company = extract_company.find(email[ start['@', end['.']]

def extract_company(email):
    return
```

The extracted value should be returned into the df extract_company

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.Series.str.extract`:

```
import pandas as pd
extract_company = pd.Series(['a@google.com', 'b@facebook.com'])
extract_company.str.extract('@(.+)\.')
```

Output:

```
          0
0    google
1  facebook
```

You can then assign it back to your `df`, for example:

```
df['extract_company'] = extract_company.str.extract('@(.+)\.')
```